# How to get the difference between dates using date fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I am trying to get the difference between two dates using date fns, but the result is NaN.

```js
import { format, differenceInCalendarDays, parseISO, formatDistance } from "date-fns";
import { ru } from 'date-fns/locale';

export function getCurrentDate() {
  const date = new Date();
  const pattern = `PPp`;
  return format(date, pattern, {locale: ru});
}

export function getDifferenceDate(startDate, endDate) {
  const start = startDate;
  const end = endDate;

  console.log(start, end)
  return differenceInCalendarDays(start, end);
}
```

Comment: have you verified that `startDate` and `endDate` are both valid `Date` objects (rather than for example, string representations of a date)?

Comment: date fns has a parse ISO method that parses the date from the string, but for what reason it outputs an invalid date

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information; you will need to parse the input dates before passing them to `differenceInCalendarDays` function. Something like:

```js
import { format, differenceInCalendarDays, parseISO, formatDistance } from "date-fns";
import { ru } from 'date-fns/locale';

export function getCurrentDate() {
  const date = new Date();
  const pattern = `PPp`;
  return format(date, pattern, {locale: ru});
}

export function getDifferenceDate(startDate, endDate) {
  const start = parseISO(startDate); // <--- Notice this
  const end = parseISO(endDate); // <--- Notice this

  console.log(start, end)
  return differenceInCalendarDays(start, end);
}
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/DarkmagentaImpartialCodec#index.js)***